# Is it fine this database schema? (more than one relationship with the same table)

Tags: mysql, nhibernate, database-design, relational-database, castle-activerecord

```
Blog
    Id
    ...
    List of Posts
    Last Post           <---
    Most Viewed Post    <---

Post
    Id
    ...
    Blog (the blog it belongs to)
```

I used to have only a `List of Posts` in the `Blog` entity, but then I had to show some Blogs table like this:

```
Blog Id  | ... |  Last Post  | Most Viewed Post
----------------------------------------------
   1     | ... |  Something  |     Post 1
   1     | ... |  Something  |     Post 10
   1     | ... |  Something  |     Post 5
   1     | ... |  Something  |     Post 4
```

and using only the `List of Posts`, and having the other fields as properties in the `Blog`, computing them in memory from the `List of Posts`, but I couldn't find a way of sorting by either `Last Post` or `Most Viewed Post` it in a SQL query (I'm using pagination, sorting by columns, etc.)

I'm using `NHibernate` with `Active Record` with `MySQL` in case it matters.

Comment: You should be able to compute those things with queries.

Comment: I would really like to know how.

Comment: Post a new question with details of your schema and the query you're trying to do.

Comment: @Barmar I could do that, but I'm not doing the queries manually. I'm trying to avoid writing the SQL queries manually, since I'm using NHibernate with ActiveRecord, and building my queries using LINQ.

Comment: It doesn't matter, show what you're trying to do, and someone familiar with those technologies should be able to help. But they need to know your table schemas.

Answer (score 0):

map the computed Properties as Formula

```
Refernce(x => x.LastPost).Formula("(Select Max(p.Id) FROM post p WHERE p.BlogId = Id)");
```

then you can use them in the query